# String format float with always 8 characters but no left padding

Tags: python, floating-point, formatting

I would like

```
1.2            -> 1.200000
12.3           -> 12.30000
1234.5         -> 1234.500
12.34444444444 -> 12.34444
```

I tried

```
value = 1234.5
s = f"{value:.8f}"
```

and similar formatting, but it does not keep always 8 characters (7 digits + decimal point).

**How to do this with `format` or `f"..." strings`?**

I know there are other solution such as `f"{value:.20f}"[:8]` but I am curious if it possible with formatting only.

Comment: Where did you learn how to specify a format?

Comment: @ScottHunter I usually look either on docs.python.org or pyformat.info, where do you usually look for this?

Comment: I'm not sure why you ever want this. People like the decimal points aligned

Comment: @wim I'm sending data to hardware which requires this precise format

Comment: What do you want to do with zero or negative values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute the length and programmatically set the number of decimals to keep:

```
value = 1234.5

import math
N = 8
n = 1+math.floor(math.log10(value))
s = f"{value:.{N-n-1}f}"
```

Output: `'1234.500'`

##### generic function

```
def fmt(value, N=8):
    import math
    if value > 0:
        v = value
    elif value < 0:
        v = -10*value
    else:
        v = 1
    n = 1+math.floor(math.log10(v))
    if n>=N-1:
        return str(round(value))
        # or overflow
        # return '!'*N
    return f"{value:.{N-n-1}f}"

l = [-12.3, -1, 0, 1, 10, 1.2, 12.3, 100, 1234.5, 12.34444444444, 123456789.9]

print('\n'.join([fmt(v) for v in l]))
```

Output:

```
-12.3000
-1.00000
0.000000
1.000000
10.00000
1.200000
12.30000
100.0000
1234.500
12.34444
123456790
```

Comment: What happens for numbers with more than 8 digits to the left of the decimal point?

Comment: This formats 1.0 too wide

Comment: @Mark is not handled, so would by 1 ;) but you can write a function for special cases

Comment: @mozway I know there are obvious ways with other functions than format such as `f"{value:.20f}"[:8]`, but I was curious if it's possible with string formatting only.

Comment: @Mark added such function ;)

Comment: @Basj not to my knowledge, and the slicing won't handle rounding and large numbers correctly ;)

Comment: [looks bad](https://tio.run/##TU/LDoIwELz3KzZcbA0g1QshwU/gB5QDkRZqypasxWgM3448YuKcdmZnZrP927cOT2lP01QrDbrz/FnZQYVQ5KnIGMwwXe/IQ1f5duUI@UxeXIaLFN@UsXydrGtksuWFEFtWA57zIpJb1QJSfiCEhydObsD6F2B/Sx18VjWLP0WEkRz1GDBm58MXmez33ByOArQjMGAQqMJGcZmIkvVk0PPdFXfx3Rnkl/WjzftcvLYUYpq@)

Comment: @Kelly I just thought of that, I should have used a floor;)

Comment: @Kelly updated (let me know if you find another flaw)

Comment: Nice set of test cases.

Comment: Formats `1234567.` too narrow

Comment: @wim not sure what to do in this case, doesn't make much sense to have a decimal separator without numbers

Comment: Why not? `1234567.` is normal syntax for a float ..

Comment: `1+math.floor(math.log10(value))` may be a problem for values near edge cases when `n` increments and the printed value rounds differently then expected with `n`.  Consider power-of-10 values scaled by 0.9999995 (for 6 digit output) and the values immediately above and below that.

Comment: @MarkRansom Re: [Nice set of test cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72608147/string-format-float-with-always-8-characters-but-no-left-padding#comment128259177_72608250). Challengs cases near the integer transition of `math.floor(math.log10(v))` and the rounded decimal printing (e.g. 9.999... to 10.0) are missing.

Comment: @chux do you mean you would multiply by the factor?

Comment: @mozway Yes  "factor" is more clear.   For N==6, values likes `0.9999995, 9.999995, 99.99995, ...` and their immediate neighbors.